# Как передать в метод render React-компонента параметр в TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend

В Компонент импортируется декоратор, который нужно передать в `render`:

```
class Preloader extends PureComponent<IPreloader, undefined> {
    //...
    render(cn: ClassDecorator) {
      //...
    }
}
```

, выше определил интерфейс:

```
export interface IPreloader {
  size?: string;
  active?: boolean;
  color?: string;
  render: (cn: ClassDecorator) => any;
}
```

Но TS ругается на него:

> TS2415: Class 'Preloader' incorrectly extends base class 'PureComponent'.
>   Types of property 'render' are incompatible.
>   Type '(cn: ClassDecorator) => Element' is not assignable to type '() => ReactNode'.

Подскажите, как корректно передать декоратор в рендер?

Comment: как вы хотите это сделать если `render` не принимает никаких аргументов?  `render(): ReactNode;`

Comment: @overthesanity покажите, пожалуйста, где такое в документации написано?

Comment: достаточно было посмотреть `@types/react`, к тому же первым типом, который перегружает `P` идет тип пропсов, а вы каким-то образом хотите `props` передать в `render`, что-то вы не доучили...

Comment: @overthesanity то есть, в обычном `react` можно, а в `@types/react` нет? Делал по [докам cn](https://github.com/alfa-laboratory/cn-decorator), без TS всё отлично работало

Comment: причем тут обычный `react` и `@types/react`, вы забежали вперед паровоза, начав одновременно изучать `react + TS`, в либе, которую вы скинули используется декоратор, который как раз таки сеттит новую функцию `render`, копируя старую, позволяя передавать аргументы, к тому же вам нужно изучить как работают декораторы, они не "импортируются"

Comment: надо параметры передавать не в метод render, а в props

Comment: https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-render-props-in-typescript-b561b00bc67c

Comment: @batman оформите свой комментарий как ответ

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach, оформил

Answer (score 1):

надо параметры передавать не в метод render, а в props